# Docker support - Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, docker

I recently learned about Docker and from a [press release](http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/10/google-bets-big-on-docker-with-app-engine-integration-open-source-container-management-tool/) that Google App Engine supports it.

The question is,

- Does it mean that we can now "package" our app using Docker (may it contain non-GAE white-listed jars) and expect it to work with Google App Engine?
- How a docker app can access the Datastore API, the TaskQueue API is there a way, or this question is irrelevant?
- If I package with Docker, say, a Spring app that access MongoDB, MySQL or whatever would it work GAE, if yes how come?

Or otherwise if this idea is not correct,

- What is the integration of Docker and Google App Engine?

Comment: You have it all a bit wrong.  They are saying that docker will be part of the managed vm backend.  It is not a deployment model for normal appengine components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of an ongoing Limited Preview [Managed VMs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/), you can subscribe to it with the following [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1XLPITmwXZkkjVLDE4ZYy-zN4Uvt5Ql59LtGU7yVZB3Y/viewform?edit_requested=true)

> Does it mean that we can now "package" our app using Docker (may it contain non-GAE white-listed jars) and expect it to work with Google App Engine?

Yes

> How a docker app can access the Datastore API, the TaskQueue API is there a way, or this question is irrelevant?

Using the regular API jars.

> If I package with Docker, say, a Spring app that access MongoDB, MySQL or whatever would it work GAE, if yes how come?

Because the underlying container run on a Google Compute Engine VMs, see the [Managed VMs documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) referenced earlier for more details.